# Passing a param using initialParam to another screen but the value of the param received is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've been working three weeks on a project using react-native, I've never used this langage before so it's still new for me.

When I pass "test" as a param to Publication screen, route.params.post displays the right value which is "test" but when I pass {user}, it displays an empty value (route.params.post = {}).
I have no problem when I pass {user} as param to the leftHeader and RightHeaderComponent, I receive the object which is not empty there.

I don't understand the issue here, why do I get an empty value when I pass {user} to another screen using initialParams ?

```
 export default function AppRouterComponent() {
      const [user, setUser] = useState({});
        useEffect(() => {
          getUser()
            .then(data => {
              return data;
            })
            .then(data => {
              setUser(data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(123123);
            });
        }, []);
      const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="home"
          screenOptions={{
            drawerType: dimensions.width >= 768 ? "permanent" : "front",
            headerLeft: () => <LeftHeaderComponent object = {user}/>,
            headerTitle: () => null,
            headerRight: () => <RightHeaderComponent object = {user}/>,
          }}
          drawerContent={(props) => DrawnerWithHeader(props)}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen}/>
          <Drawer.Screen name="View/Edit user info" component={UserInfo} initialParams={{ post: user}}/>
          <Drawer.Screen name="user preferences" component={UserSettings} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Publication" component={PublicationScreen} initialParams={{ post: "test"}}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    }




  /*The other screen, when I use the debugger to check route.params.post value, it displays an empty object*/
  export default function UserInformationScreen({navigation, route}) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <UserInformationComponent object = {route.params.post}/>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: how do you navigate to the UserInformationScreen?

Comment: What object do you receive if you log the `route.params`?

Comment: @omer.ersoy by using           <Drawer.Screen name="View/Edit user info" component={UserInfo} initialParams={{ post: user}}/>

Comment: @omer.ersoy {UserInfo}  = "../../../screen/UserInformationScreen";

Comment: @enzou I receive {post:{}} it's empty

Comment: Aah ok, yes you Drawer.Screen is catching the first value of state, so dont matter if this value is updated because you render doesnt depends on that. You must wait until you get the value of async request, you could use a `<Loader>` component, then you can use a ternary to render the Loader until you get the data